# Sorting a list of points with Java

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of point objects, which I want to sort by a certain coordinate, say the x-values. Does Java provide any useful mechanisms or should I avail myself of one of the common sort algorithms?

Answer (score 21):

Yes create a custom [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) , and use it to sort list of points

```
class Point{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point() {
    }
}
```

---

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
points.add(new Point(1, 2));
points.add(new Point(60, 50));
points.add(new Point(50, 3));
Collections.sort(points,new Comparator<Point>() {

public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
    return Integer.compare(o1.getX(), o2.getX());
}
});
```

Answer (score 5):

In `Point` class you should implement [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface with generic type `<Point>` and use `Collections.sort` (java.util package) for sorting `List<Point>`

Assume:

```
class Point implements Comparable<Point>{
    int compareTo(Point other){ /* your logic */}
}

List<Point> list = new ArrayList<Point>();
/* adding points */
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should either make your point class to implement Comparable interface or provide sort() method with your own Comparator object, which tells sort() how to order your objects. There a lot of examples around here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like a [Bean Comparator](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/bean-comparator/) so you don't have to keep creating custom Comparators.