# Sorting a list of objects based on different data members in java

Tags: java, string, sorting, collections, comparable

I have this class:

```
public class Friend {

private String name;
private String location;
private String temp;
private String humidity;

public String getTemp() {
    return temp;
}

public void setTemp(String temp) {
    this.temp = temp;
}

public String getHumidity() {
    return humidity;
}

public void setHumidity(String humidity) {
    this.humidity = humidity;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
}
```

I want to sort a List based on name, location, temp and humidity based on user input.

 **EDIT:**The user specifies by which data member the sorting has to be done.

 What is the easiest way to do this?

 Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178092/sorting-a-list-of-points-with-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java has a static function called [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) which sorts a (generified) List of objects given a custom Comparator which, given two objects of the same type, determines which one is ordered before the other.

Your task is to write a function which creates a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which orders the objects based on its arguments and the user specified sort order.  For example:

```java
public Comparator<Friend> getComparator(final String sortBy) {
  if ("name".equals(sortBy)) {
    return new Comparator<Friend>() {
      @Override int compare(Friend f1, Friend f2) 
        return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
      }
    };
  } else if ("location".equals(sortBy)) {
    return new Comparator<Friend>() {
      @Override int compare(Friend f1, Friend f2) 
        return f1.getLocation().compareTo(f2.getLocation());
      }
    };
  } else if ("temp".equals(sortBy)) {
    // ...
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid sort field '" + sortBy + "'");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you want to sort them by four different standards, implementing Comparable does not make sense.  In this case, you may find that creating different Comparators for each sort-by parameter.  However, you could implement Comparable for the most logical sort-by field, such as name.  Otherwise, comparators are the way to go.

```
public class FriendNameComparator extends Comparator<Friend> {

    // assuming both are non-null for code simplicity; you may wish to change that
    public int compare(Friend f1, Friend f2) {
        return f1.getName().compareTo(f2.getName());
    }
}

public class FriendLocationComparator extends Comparator<Friend> {

    // assuming both are non-null for code simplicity; you may wish to change that
    public int compare(Friend f1, Friend f2) {
        return f1.getLocation().compareTo(f2.getLocation());
    }
}

// and so forth
```

Then, you can use the sort function of the Collections utility class to sort by the given comparator.

```
Collections.sort(friendsList, new FriendNameComparator()); // sorts by name
Collections.sort(friendsList, new FriendLocationComparator()); // sorts by location
// etc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List list=new ArrayList();
```

Use If else if for each criteria:

```
if(location ){
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator () {
             public int compare(YourObject o1, YourObject o2) {
                    return o1.getLocation().compareTo(o2.getLocation());
                }

        });

    }

    } else if(temp ){

    ........
    }
    .......
```