# Java sort map or array

Tags: java

I have code:

```
    List<ModelMap> nameCustomer = new ArrayList<ModelMap>();

    for (int i=1;i<150;i++) {
                    ModelMap map = new ModelMap();
                    map.put("name", "nazwa " + i);
                    map.put("surname", "nazwisko " + i);
                    map.put("number", "123 ");
                    nameCustomer.add(map);
                }

            ModelMap[] result = new ModelMap[nameCustomer.size()];
            ModelMap[] rowsArray = nameCustomer.toArray(result);
```

How can I sort nameCustomer (or rowsArray) by surname or number?

Comment: Look at `Arrays.sort()` for the array and `Collections.sort()` for the list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Collections.sort(nameCustomer, comparator)` method to sort your list. For that you have to write the code for your Comparator.The code for Comparator will be -

```
public Comparator<ModelMap> getComparator(final String sortBy){
   if ("surname".equals(sortBy)) {
   return new Comparator<ModelMap>() {
   @Override int compare(ModelMap m1, ModelMap m2) 
    return m1.getSurname().compareTo(m2.getSurname());
   }};} 
     else if (condition) {// ...  }
      else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid sort field '" + sortBy + "'"); }
       }
```

I am assuming that you  have a `getSurname` method written in your ModelMap class to get the surname. If not then write it to make the above code work.

You can visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527990/sorting-a-list-of-objects-based-on-different-data-members-in-java) for further help. Cheers !!

Comment: I don't have method in ModelMap class. How should be write this method?

Comment: public string getSurname(){return surname} write this in your ModelMap class

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that defines your sorting criteria,
then you can use [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) for arrays, or `Collections.sort` for Lists, or dump everything into a `SortedSet` (e.g., `TreeSet`)

Comment: How should be write my Comparator?

Comment: @faszynski all of those questions you have can be answered by a very simple google search...

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the Collections.Sort package. Lists maintain "natural ordering" to maintain consistency. e.g.

```
    List<Name> names = Arrays.asList(nameArray);
    Collections.sort(names);
    System.out.println(names);
```

Comment: But how to do that if you have a two-level List/Map or similar structure ? The only solution I see is to implement a custom iterator to return a specified sublevel-key, then extract it as an array, then finally sort it.

Comment: As the other answers state, you should use a custom Comparator.

Comment: So this list does not answer the question because it tells OP that `Collections.sort()` does use natural ordering, which is not what he wants...

Comment: Yes, I read the doc one more time, and effectively it is easily possible to implement such a thing, and smarter to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

using the Colections.sort() and give it a custom Comparator class implementation, which will do a string compare by surname.

Or use a LinkedHashMap, which has consistency after put() ang get() and keys sorted.

I hope it helps!

Comment: How should be write my Comparator?

Comment: Exactly what I wrote in profile: the fish needed ( the complete source coe ready to copy-paste)  not the fishing knowledge...Not even an upvote for accepted answer, what a shame!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own iterator on List, which could be parametrized to return only the inner key you specified.

Then, "iterating" with a standard sorter around it does the trick.