# How to sort ArrayLists?

Tags: java, sorting, datetime

I have some lists that contain elements of type DataTime( Joda-time ). How can I sort them by date?
It will be great if somebody gave link to the example...

Comment: Look into `Collections.sort` and `Comparator`.

Comment: @nkr I think you mean Comparator

Comment: Hint: sort by timestamp.

Comment: Can you show the outline of the code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the objects of your list implement the `Comparable` interface, you can use

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

where `list` is your `ArrayList`.

---

Relevant Javadocs:

- [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)
- [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html)
- [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

---

**Edit:** If you want to sort a list of a custom class that contains a `DateTime` field in a similar way, you would have to implement the `Comparable` interface yourself. For example,

```
public class Profile implements Comparable<Profile> { 
    DateTime date;
    double age; 
    int id; 

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Profile other) {
        return date.compareTo(other.getDate());  // compare by date
    }
}
```

Now, if you had a `List` of `Profile` instances, you could employ the same method as above, namely `Collections.sort(list)` where `list` is the list of `Profile`s.

Comment: And what if the ArrayList contains objects of class Profile

public Profile{
   DateTime date;
   Double age;
   int id;
}

How can i sort it by date?

Comment: Profile is a class, that i wrote myself

Answer (score 6):

[`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) already implements Comparable you just need to use `Collections.sort()`

Comment: And what if the ArrayList contains objects of class Profile  
  
public Profile{  
   DateTime date;  
   Double age;  
   int id;  
}  
  
How can i sort it by date?

Comment: You need to implement custom comparator in this case

Comment: @Stas0n see the edit on my post

Comment: Could you show a sketch of the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178092/sorting-a-list-of-points-with-java