# how to set a field as a key and sort the class

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections, dictionary

```
class People {
  int height;
  int weight;
}

List<People> list = new ArrayList<People> ();
```

I'd like to sort the list with field 'height' as the key.

Is there any predefined method that I can use? How can I set height as my key?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Comparator` that takes a key and sorts it by that field

**Also See**

- [Reference to similar problem/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178092/sorting-a-list-of-points-with-java)

Comment: can I also use Comparator to rank tuples.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your class implement `Comparable<People>`, which creates what's called a *natural order*, but it doesn't seem intuitive that people are always "more" or "less" based on height.  A better approach is probably to create a `Comparator`, which you can then use with `Collections.sort` to sort the list.

(As a note: It's customary in Java for the class name be the singular of what the class represents, so in your case, it would be more legible to name it `Person` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

-In order to put some objects into a specific order usually it is recommended to use a Set from Java Collection Framework.And than u have 2 options:
Implement in the same class `Comparable` and override the method `compareTo`.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Implement in a new class the interface `Comparator` and override the `compare` method.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

In your case using Lists you can still do these too and than call the method `.sort()` From `Collections`.

```
class HightSort implements Comparator<People > {
    public int compare(People one, People two) {
    return one.hight-two.hight;
    }
    }

 Collections.sort(list);
```