# Find an object inside ArrayList Java

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of objects. Each object is of type Player (one of the classes that I have).
Each Player object has a getName() method and a getValue() method. The getValue method is of integer type.
All the Player objects go into an ArrayList, listOfPlayers. 
How do I find a PLayer object with the highest getValue()?

I know there is a method called Collections.max(), but for me it only seems to work if the ArrayList is just full of integers.

Thanks

Comment: Use a comparator, sort the list, retrieve the first element. Iterate through all elements and get the one with the highest.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection, java.util.Comparator)

Comment: if you just have to find it once, just do a linear search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with comparator

```
Collection.max(collection, customComparator);
```

---

**Also See**

- [How to use custom `Comparator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178092/sorting-a-list-of-points-with-java)

Answer (score 2):

You need to Implement Comparator for your class like this

```
Comparator<Player> cmp = new Comparator<Player>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o1.getValue()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.getValue()));
    }
};
```

then call

```
  Collections.max(listOfPlayers, cmp);
```