# Getting max value from an arraylist of objects?

Tags: java

Is there an easy way to get the max value from one field of an object in an arraylist of objects? For example, out of the following object, I was hoping to get the highest value for the Value field.

Example arraylist I want to get the max value for ValuePairs.mValue from.

```
ArrayList<ValuePairs> ourValues = new ArrayList<>();
outValues.add(new ValuePairs("descr1", 20.00));
outValues.add(new ValuePairs("descr2", 40.00));
outValues.add(new ValuePairs("descr3", 50.00));
```

Class to create objects stored in arraylist:

```
public class ValuePairs {

    public String mDescr;
    public double mValue;

    public ValuePairs(String strDescr, double dValue) {
        this.mDescr = strDescr;
        this.mValue = dValue;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the max value for mValue by doing something like (which I know is incorrect):

```
double dMax = Collections.max(ourValues.dValue);
```

dMax should be 50.00.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a `Comparator` with [`Collections.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to let it know which is greater in comparison.

---

**Also See**

- [How to use custom `Comparator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178092/sorting-a-list-of-points-with-java)

Answer (score 32):

With Java 8 you can use `stream()` together with it's predefined `max()` function and `Comparator.comparing()` functionality with lambda expression:

```
ValuePairs maxValue = values.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(v -> v.getMValue())).get();
```

Instead of using a lambda expression, you can also use the method reference directly:

```
ValuePairs maxValue = values.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(ValuePairs::getMValue)).get();
```

Comment: Is there a way to get *all* the `ValuePairs` matching the `.max()`?

Comment: That would be something like this after you have found out the max value: `List<ValuePairs> maxValues = ourValues.stream().filter(v -> v.mValue == maxValue.mValue).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 9):

This has been answered multiple time already, but since it's the first result on google I will give a Java 8 answer with an example.

Take a look at the [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) feature. Then you can get the max form an List of Objects like this:

```
List<ValuePairs> ourValues = new ArrayList<>();

ourValues.stream().max(comparing(ValuePairs::getMValue)).get()
```

By the way in your example, the attributes should be private. You can then access them with a getter.

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate over the list comparing/finding the max value `O(N)`. If you need to do this often replace the list with a [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) `O(1)` to find the max.

Answer (score 0):

***Here fist and last is intervals between two indexes of arraylist you can also get for a complete list by removing them and i=0 upto size of float list.***

// for min value

public String getMinValue(ArrayList list, int first, int last) {

```
        List<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Float prova2 = ((Double) list.get(i)).floatValue();
            floatList.add(prova2);
        }
        float min = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        String minValue = "";

        for (int i = first; i < last; i++) {


            if (floatList.get(i) < min) {
                min = floatList.get(i);
            }
        }
        minValue = String.format("%.1f", min);
        return minValue;
    }
```

// for max value

```
    public String getMaxValue(List<Object> list, int first, int last) {

        List<Float> floatList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Float prova2 = ((Double) list.get(i)).floatValue();
            floatList.add(prova2);
        }

        float max = Float.MIN_VALUE;
        String maxValue = "";

        for (int i = first; i < last; i++) {


            if (floatList.get(i) > max) {
                max = floatList.get(i);
            }
        }
        maxValue = String.format("%.1f", max);
        return maxValue;
    }
```