# Most efficient way to find object with highest value

Tags: java, arrays

I have a dynamically created array of `Box` objects where the user inputs an amount of boxes then enters their dimensions

Each `Box` object has multiple variables, but I'm interested in finding the box with the highest `totalArea` variable as i'm trying to figure out which size fills up a space the most efficiently

I can do this very simply with:

```
int amount = 0, boxNum;

for (int i=0; i<boxes.length;i++)
    if (boxes[i].totalArea > amount){
        amount = boxes[i].totalArea;
        boxNum = i+1;
    }
```

but I feel as if i'm doing more work than necessary by declaring three variables. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve this. My first thought was using an enhanced for loop, but that's a no go, as finding the current index of the iteration isn't a viable route. Now it's probably not a big deal, but for the sake of optimization and learning, is there a better, faster way to do this?

edit: This example is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338686/java-getting-max-value-from-an-arraylist-of-objects) as `Collections.max()` is used for collections like `arrayLists`, not generic arrays

Comment: Better and faster are not synonymous. You can make the code a little cleaner, perhaps, but not significantly faster. At least not in a single-threaded environment.

Comment: Why would a box even have a `totalArea` field? Does it not have dimensions?

Comment: If you need to find the maximum area and the index at which it occurs, you do need to have two variables.

Comment: You do not strictly need the `amount` variable, however, leaving it out would make the program slightly more complicated and slower.

Comment: @shmosel the program calculates the most efficient size box to fill a larger space. `totalArea` is  the area of the box * how many boxes fit in the space.  This allows me to find the best fit, plus the percentage of space that is unused