# How to get min/max from ArrayList based on its object attribute values?

Tags: arraylist, kotlin, comparable

What I want to achieve is to get min/max attribute value of object from `ArrayList<Object>`. For example if `Object` has attribute `weight`(float), I want heaviest object from the list.

I've tried to implement Comparable to get max/min value but this returns same value for min and same for max for some reason. (I don't know if it works with floats)

```
    val maxVal: Float = arrayList.max().floatVal1
    val minVal: Float = arrayList.min().floatVal1

    data class CustomObject(var val1: String, var floatVal1: Float , var floatVal2: Float?, var floatVal3: Float?, var floatVal4: Float?): Comparable<CustomObject>{
        override fun compareTo(other: CustomObject) = (floatVal1 - other.floatVal1).toInt()
    }
```

That specific question from duplicate post does not show me how to get max/min value based on Float. That's the problem. If I want to modify Comparator it accepts only Int. And i cant use that stream feature because my app is for API 23+ not 24+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - getting max value from an arraylist of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338686/java-getting-max-value-from-an-arraylist-of-objects)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`minBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-by.html) and [`maxBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by.html):

```
 val minObject: CustomObject? = arrayList.minBy { it.floatVal1 }
 val maxObject: CustomObject? = arrayList.maxBy { it.floatVal1 }
```

Comment: These give you the `CustomObject` instances that have the smallest/largest `floatVal1` values in the list, is that not what you want? If you want that actual smallest/largest value, you can read it from these objects as well.

Answer (score 21):

```
val maxObj: Object? = arrayList.maxByOrNull { it.floatVal1 }
val minObj: Object? = arrayList.minByOrNull { it.floatVal2 }
```

maxBy, minBy are [deprecated](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by.html) since Kotlin 1.4

Comment: What's the benefit of using `maxByOrNull` over `minBy` as suggested by [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52466423/3025856)? Can you edit your answer to call out this difference, and explain why or when it might be preferred? Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyCaney because they are deprecated.  Since maxByOrNull, minByOrNull returns a nullable object we can check and avoid crashes.

Answer (score 4):

This return non-null types:

```
val max = list.maxOf { it.value }
val min = list.minOf { it.value }
```

Comment: If your integer values are nullable then max or min values need to be checked whether if NaN or not. Ex: if(max.isNan())

Answer (score 1):

Below Code returns Max value of your parameter in list of objects.

**Ex)100 is max marks obtained all students**

```
list.maxOf { it.yourParameter } // Returns Max value of yourParameter value in list of objects
```

Below Code returns Object of Max value of your parameter in list of objects.

**Ex)Student object who got 100 marks**

```
list.maxBy { it.yourParameter } // Returns Object of Max of yourParameter value in list of objects
```