# Printing return max from list

Tags: java

I need method which will return person with the highest salary. I can't use void method.

```
private void persons() {
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Employee("Pa", "Ko", 2500));
    persons.add(new Employee("Ku", "No", 5000));
    persons.add(new Student("Ka", "Sl", 500));
```

I have tried something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
private Person bestPayed(List<Person> persons) {
    persons.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getSalary));
    return Person ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338686/getting-max-value-from-an-arraylist-of-objects

Comment: why they are different classes? your instance Employee and Student are different, it's better to use the same instance and define in a property in each class role of the person.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting max value from an arraylist of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338686/getting-max-value-from-an-arraylist-of-objects)

Comment: You need to return `persons.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getSalary))` instead of `Person`.

Comment: @geobreze your code is similar to mine but still it prints nothing but "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: To print something, try using `System.out.println(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stream is almost ok because it returns `Optional<Person>`, then you need a `get()` to ensure return the `Person` object, not the optional.

Or, as Alex said into comments, use `orElse` to avoid exceptions.

So you can use this line into the method:

```java
public Person bestPayed(List<Person> persons) {
  return persons.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getSalary)).get();
}
```

Or using `orElse`:

```
public Person bestPayed(List<Person> persons) {
  return persons.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getSalary)).orElse(null);
}
```

Is better using `orElse()` because if your list is empty, then `Optional<Person>` will be empty too and trying to `get()` it will throw an exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

Also your code fails (maybe is a typo) because you are returning `Person`, and, what is Person? You have to return the result of the stream.

And to output the object you can call the method like this:

```
System.out.println("BestPayed = "+bestPayed(persons));
```

And add a `toString()` method in your `Person` class. This method is to output the object as an string, and depends on what attributes your class have.

For example, assuming your class has `name`, `surname` and `salary` your `toString()` could be something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person [name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + ", salary=" + salary + "]";
}
```

But you can add or delete what you want to output.

And running this code the console output is:

```
BestPayed = Person [name=Ku, surname=No, salary=5000]
```

Also if you only want to display the salary, use this:

```
System.out.println("Best salary = "+bestPayed(persons).getSalary());
```

Comment: It's better to use `orElse` instead of `get()`, cause if list will be empty it will return `Optional.empty()` which will throw en exception on `get()`

Comment: That's true. I will add into the explanation. Also, as the list is added I've assumed there will exists at least one value.

Comment: Btw i'd better return `Optional` from method and worked with it in functional style like `bestPayed(persons).ifPresent(System.out::println)` :)