# Java sort through 3 classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting

how can I sort Event by index? 
 
simple view of my project:

```
class Event{
    int index; 
}

class EventField{
    Event[] field;
}

class Action{
    EventField ev;
    ev.sort();    // Sort event in field EventField by index
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) with [`Comparator<Event>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which is using [`Integer.compare()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29)

```
Arrays.sort(ev.field, new Comparator<Event>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Event e1, Event e2) {
        return Integer.compare(e1.index, e2.index)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement method in `EventField`

```
class EventField{
    Event[] field;

    public void sort(){ Arrays.sort(field, yourCustomComparatorInstance }
}
```

that does sorting using a custom `Comparator` on `Event`

**Related:**

- [Sorting a list of points with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178092/sorting-a-list-of-points-with-java)

**See**

- [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: As your related question, don't use `return o1.getX() - o2.getX();`, as it could overflow when you compare a number close to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` with a one close to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. See [this](https://ideone.com/ykTwQr).

Answer (score 0):

In java you have 2 ways to define order you can create a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for creating your sort strategy, or define [*natural-order*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) of your class implementing [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Example using Comparator:

```
class Event{

private int index;
public static final Comparator<Event> INDEX_COMPARATOR = new MyComparator();

//TODO define getters and setter equals & hashCode cause it's strong recommended

static class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyClass>{

            @Override
            public int compare(Event o1, Event o2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(o1.index).compareTo(o2.index);
            }    
}

}
```

And then in EventField.

Example:

```
class EventField{
    Event[] fields;

   public void sort(){
     Arrays.sort(fields,Event.INDEX_COMPARATOR );
   }

 }
```

Read more : [Collections#sort(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

If  you want to define natural-ordering of your class just define

```
public class Event implements Comparable<Event>{
        private int index;

        //define getter&setter & recommended equals & hashCode    

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Event o) {
           return Integer.valueOf(index).compareTo(o.index);
        }
}
```

And in EventField code:

```
   Arrays.sort(fields); // where fields is Event[]
```

Answer (score 0):

If events are naturally something you'll be comparing a lot in your program, you can extend the `Comparable` interface:

```
public class Event implements Comparable<Event> {
    private int index;

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Event o) {
        return index == o.getIndex() ? 0 : (index > o.getIndex() ? 1 : -1);
    } 
}
```

Then you can call `Arrays.sort(ev.getField())`.  If the objects in 'field' are always going to be sorted, then you can just keep its objects sorted whenever you add something to it.