# What is a better method to sort strings alphabetically in a linked list that is reading in lines from a text file?

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

```
public class ContactList {

    private ContactNode head;
    private ContactNode last;
    public ContactNode current;
    public ContactList value;

    public ContactList() {}

    public void addNode(ContactNode input) {
        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = input;
            this.last = input;
        } else last.setNext(input);
        input.setPrev(last);
        this.last = input;
    }

    public void traverse() {
        System.out.println();
        current = this.head;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.getName() + " ");
            System.out.println("");
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


    public void insertNewFirstNode(String value) {
        ContactNode newNode = new ContactNode(value);
        head = newNode;
        if (last == null) {
            last = head;
        }
    }

    public void sort() {
        ContactList sorted = new ContactList();
        current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            int index = 0;

            if ((current.getName() != null)) {
                index = this.current.getName().compareTo(current.getName());
                if (index == 1) {
                    sorted.insertNewFirstNode(current.getName());
                }
                current = current.getNext();
            } else if ((current != null)) {
                System.out.print(sorted + "\n");
            }
        }
    } // end contactList
```

Main Method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ContactMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileReader filepath = new FileReader("data1.txt");
            Scanner k = new Scanner(filepath);
            ContactList myList = new ContactList();
            while (k.hasNextLine()) {
                String i = k.nextLine();
                myList.addNode(new ContactNode(i));
            }

            myList.traverse();
            myList.sort();
            myList.traverse();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found. ");
        }
    }
}
```

Node Class:

```
public class ContactNode {

    private String name;
    public int index;
    private ContactNode prev;
    public ContactNode next;

    ContactNode(String a) {
        name = a;
        index = 0;
        next = null;
        prev = null;
    }

    public ContactNode getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public ContactNode getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setNext(ContactNode newnext) {
        next = newnext;
    }

    public void setPrev(ContactNode newprevious) {
        prev = newprevious;
    }

    public void setName(String a) {
        name = a;
    }

    public void setIndex(int b) {
        index = b;
    }
}
```

I am making a program for fun that reads in contact information from a text file and puts them into a Linked List. I want to create a `sort()` method to sort each node or name alphabetically. I've done a good amount of research and my method only prints code like: `ContactList@282c0dbe`, by as many lines as my text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is `ContactList@282c0dbe`?

It is class name follow by at sign and hash code at the end, hash code of the object.All classes in Java inherit from the Object class, directly or indirectly . The Object class has some basic methods like clone(), toString(), equals(),.. etc.  The default `toString()` method in Object prints `“class name @ hash code”.`

What is the **solution**?

You need to override `toString` method  in `ContactList` class because it is going to give you clear information about the object in readable format that you can understand.

The merit about overriding `toString`:

> Help the programmer for **logging** and **debugging of Java program**
>
> Since **toString** is defined in **java.lang.Object** and does not give valuable information, so it is
>      good practice to override it for subclasses.

```
  @override
  public String toString(){
     // I assume name is the only field in class test
     return name + " " + index;
  }
```

For sorting, you should implement Comparator interface since your object does not have [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). In better sense, if you want to define an external controllable ordering behavior, this can override the default ordering behavior

[read more about Comparator interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 0):

[You need custom `Comparator` for sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178092/sorting-a-list-of-points-with-java), and to pretty print your `List` you need to implement `toString()` in `ContactList` class