# Sorting arrays in 3 steps in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays representing points in a 3D space, `position[]` for XYZ and `colors[]` for RGB, both with size `3*total_points` (e.g. `position[0]` is `X`, `position[1]` is Y, and `position[2]` is Z coordinate of point 0, and `color[0]` is the Red value, `color[1]` is Green, and `color[2]` is Blue).

What I need to do is basically sort all points in 3 steps:

1. Sort based on X (`position[0]`)
2. Then sort based on Y (`position[1]`)
3. Then sort based on Z (`position[2]`)

What is the most efficient way of doing this in Java?

What I have in mind is simply doing a bubble-sort -like approach and swap, and do this three times.

```
for (int i=0; i<position.length; i++){
  for (int j=0; j<position.length; j++){
    if(position[i] > position[j]){
    swap (position[i], position[j]);
   }
  }
}

// and do this for position[i+1] (i.e. Y) and then position[i+2] (i.e. Z)
```

Comment: Better approach will be creating a class point with Integer x,y,z . Instead of array ,use ArrayList along with comparator .

Comment: @RishabhMaurya And in the point class implement some sort of [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). As a bonus if you implement Comparable you can use some prebuilt methods in java that can sort your list more efficiently than a bubble sort

Comment: No, that u can perform in Collections.sort()

Comment: I never used `comparator` or `collection.sort()`. Can you reply with snippets?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178092/sorting-a-list-of-points-with-java

Comment: Don't you actually have an array position[][]? Because here you seem to sort x comparatively to x, y and then z. And then y to x, y and z, etc. Don't you want to sort first by x, then sort the rows by y that have a same x, and then the rows by z that have same x and y?

Also, I prefer selection sort (for each row, you compare to following rows and swap with the one that matches the most your ordering criteria) than bubble sort but that just because I find it cleaner.

Also I agree with @RishabhMaurya that it would be best to create a point Class and use a comparator.

Comment: @TinaJ Have u got the answer ?

Comment: Looks like the last answer is not correct.

Comment: @Maaaatt some parts of the source code was given to me. You are right. I need to re-write it as a class.

Comment: Can somebody improve the current answer?

Answer (score 1):

One key point of object-oriented programming is *abstraction*. To achieve it, you should create a class that represents a coloured 3D point, such as:

```
public class Point {

    private final int x;

    private final int y;

    private final int z;

    private int red;

    private int green;

    private int blue;

    public Point(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ", " + z + ")";
    }

    // TODO getters for x, y and z, plus getters & setters for red, green and blue
}
```

Note: I've added a very useful `toString()` method that will help you debug your code. Getters and setters are left as an exercise :)

Now, if you have an array of points, i.e. `Point[] points`, you can use the built-in [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) utility method, which accepts an array and a [`Comparator<Point>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
Point[] points = new Point[] {
    new Point(2, 3, 1), 
    new Point(2, 1, 4), 
    new Point(2, 1, 5) };

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points)); // [(2, 3, 1), (2, 1, 4), (2, 1, 5)]

Comparator<Point> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Point::getX)
    .thenComparingInt(Point::getY)
    .thenComparingInt(Point::getZ);

Arrays.sort(points, comparator);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points)); // [(2, 1, 4), (2, 1, 5), (2, 3, 1)]
```

Note: I'm using [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-) utility method to create a human-readable string representation of the array.

Pay attention to the definition of the `Comparator<Point> comparator` variable: there I'm stating that I want a comparator that will order points based on the `int` value returned by the `Point.getX()` method, then, if equal, order will be determined by the `int` value returned by the `Point.getY()` method and, finally, if still equal, order will be determined by the `int` value returned by the `Point.getZ()` method. This is what the [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) and [`Comparator.thenComparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) methods are used for.

Answer (score -2):

As is mentioned in the other answer, abstraction is a key point (i.e. from your three arrays of ints that loosely represent a set of points to an array of actual Points). This way, you always have the three expected coordinates together every time you handle them.

To further improve on the answer, you would probably gain from separating even more:

```
class Point {
    int x, y, z; // plus getters/setters
}

class Color {
    int r, g, b; // dito
}

class ColoredPoint {
     Point point;
     Color color;
}
```

Now you have the point and the color separate when you don't need them, but together when you do (as you needed in the original question IIUC). This is called "separation of concern" - a position in space and a color are different beasts, it's best to keep them apart.

With respect to sorting, you can also do all kinds of sorting by using different Comparators.

```
Comparator<Point> pointComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Point::getX)
    .thenComparingInt(Point::getY)
    .thenComparingInt(Point::getZ);
// and 
Comparator<Color> colorComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Color::getR)
    .thenComparingInt(Color::getG)
    .thenComparingInt(Color::getB);
```

Because you used composition to combine Point and Color together, you can reuse those comparators for your ColoredPoint if needed:

```
Comparator<ColoredPoint> cpComparator =
    Comparator.comparing(ColoredPoint::getPoint, pointComparator)
    .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(ColoredPoint::getColor, colorComparator));
```

This is better than my previous answer, which looked like this:

```
class Point implements Comparable<Point> {
    int x, y, z;

    // you can also create a separate Comparator<Point> 
    // to move the compare code outside of Point
    int compareTo(Point other) {
        // compare by position in space
        int result = this.x - other.x;
        result = (result == 0) ? result : this.y - other.y;
        result = (result == 0) ? result : this.z - other.z;
        return result;
}

Point[] arrayOfPoints = //...
Arrays.sort(arrayOfPoints);
// or
List<Point> listOfPoints = //...
Collections.sort(listOfPoints);
```

Again due to separation of concern, the point does not really need to know how you want it sorted.

Comment: Please also explain your idea and what you have changed. Posting code alone, even if it solves the problem, is often no good way in helping OP to understand the solution.

Comment: Can somebody improve the current answer?

Comment: Edited for explanation. The other answer is good, added some words on separation of concern which usually good design.