# Sort arrayList of Objects by Alphabetical order

Tags: java, sorting, search, arraylist

So I have an `ArrayList` of object 'Book' (The Item objects contain data of Title, Author, ID) and the object class' `getTitle()` method returns the title of the book as a string. How would I `mergeSort` the existing `ArrayList` into a new `ArrayList` of 'Item' that's ordered Alphabetically by title?

I also need to create a method called `searchTitle()` that takes user input of String as a parameter and uses binary searching to find the book title in the newly sorted list and then if it finds it, it will return the entire Item with the matching title.

I know how binary searching works I'm just not sure how I'm going to do that with the strings that the `Book.getTitle()` method will return...

Comment: look into Comparators

Comment: first part of question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178092/sorting-a-list-of-points-with-java/5178106 

Second part you can look into `compare` method

Comment: What's the relationship between `Item` and `Book`?

Comment: I think you're looking for `books.sort(Comparator.comparing(Book::getTitle));`.

Comment: As for the binary search, just call [`Collection.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-java.util.Comparator-) with the same comparator.

Comment: You may also consider building a `Map<String, Book> booksByTitle` and using it instead of binary search.